# Get address and device assigned by openvpn

Tags: openvpn

An OpenVPN client can dynamically allocate a network interface device (e.g. `tun0`) for a connection to a server which can dynamically issue an IP address to the client.

Given a shell script that launches the OpenVPN client (which successfully establishes a server connection), how can I find out the network interface, the assigned client IP address and the server's IP address from within the script?

The ideal answer would present a way to obtain this data using OpenVPN tools without having to make assumptions and deductions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `up` script to write the information to the filesystem and then read it from within the script.

By adding

```
--script-security 2 --up "/path/to/up.sh /path/to/dir"
```

to the invocation of `openvpn`, the script at `/path/to/up.sh` will be executed. It will receive command-line arguments and the first of them will be `/path/to/dir` which is somewhere explicit to write the information so that the invoking shell script can find it. The arguments that follow are defined by OpenVPN (see the man page) to be:

```
tun_dev tun_mtu link_mtu ifconfig_local_ip ifconfig_remote_ip [ init | restart ]
```

So, the following example script writes the required information to files in the given directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $2 > $1/interface
echo $5 > $1/ip
```

(The `--script-security` argument is required to permit the `--up` script to be user-defined.)

Once the client's own IP address is known, the server's address can be deduced given certain assumptions:

- it is the first usable address in the subnetwork (the OpenVPN documentation states this as fact)
- the subnet mask used by the server is known (in CIDR notation)

Assuming these, the [ipcalc](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/ipcalc/) tool can be used to return the server's address:

```
ipcalc $(</path/to/dir/ip)/$netmask | grep HostMin | awk '{print $2}'
```

Currently, the netmask fact needs to be agreed in advance, unless there is some way that I am unaware of that can discover this automatically. It would be good to see any answer that resolves this issue or, hopefully, a better way to answer the question that doesn't require use of an `up` script or the `ipcalc` kludge.